# Replace zip with truncated version

Tags: command-line, zip

I have multiple zip files structured like `blah1/blah2/blah3/dirs/files` where the blah directories are single folders, and multiple folders and files reside in the dirs and files levels. Is there any way to—preferrably in one line—modify the zip archive(s) so that they are structured like `dirs/files`?

Comment: What OS? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2. I can't find anything to pipe from unzip to zip. The _junk-paths_ option does more than I want. A lot of solutions change how they create the zip (by `cd` into the appropriate directory), but I don't have that option. Also, my command-line kung fu is severely lacking, so even figuring out how to loop over the zip files is challenging, but I think I can figure that out. I was hoping for a one-liner because I'm not sure if unzipping the contents, cd, and then zip would affect subsequent iterations; the artifacts are undesirable.

Comment: 7z has a command line.  And if you can't do it without separately extracting and zipping, i.e. if you have to extract and modify and rezip and you cannot see a one liner, no good piping option.. ,or xargas or anything,  then the sure way would be to make a batch file. Extract to temp directory blah. Zip temp directory blah